# Перемещение по строкам. Удаление целой строки.

Tags: pascal

Имеется некий файл. Каким образом можно перейти к определенной строке и удалить определенной кол-во строк. Вроде что-то надо сделать через цикл и (end of line), но вот как, не могу сообразить. Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае такое изменение над файлом нельзя произвести: после удаления нескольких строк все последующие данные файла должны быть сдвинуты назад, на место удалённых строк.

Теоретически, есть возможность открыть файл на чтение и запись одновременно, а дальше использовать функции для работы с файлами для «тонкой» перезаписи файла (см., например, FilePos, Seek, FileSize, BlockRead и BlockWrite тут http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/filefunctions.html ).

Гораздо проще прочесть данные в память (или другой файл) и перезаписать исходный файл полностью.